# How can I search for strings and integers in the same way in N1QL?

Tags: php, couchbase, sql++

So I have this PHP function:

```
public static function findByPageAndFieldContains($recordsPerPage, $page, $field, $searchterm) {
    $query = CouchbaseN1qlQuery::fromString('SELECT * FROM `public_portal` WHERE `collection`=$collection AND `'.$field.'` LIKE "%'.$searchterm.'%" ORDER BY `_id` limit $limit offset $offset');
    $query->options['$collection'] = static::COLLECTION_NAME;
    //$query->options['$field'] = $field;
    $query->options['$limit'] = $recordsPerPage;
    $query->options['$offset'] = $recordsPerPage*($page-1);
    //$query->options['$searchterm'] = $searchterm;

    $result = DB::getDB()->query($query);
    //var_dump($query);
    //var_dump($result);
    $objects = array();
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $object = new static($row->{"public_portal"});
        $object->setId($row->{"public_portal"}->{"_id"});
        $objects[] = $object;
    }
    //var_dump($objects);
    return $objects;
}
```

This query is vulnerable to n1ql injection. I know. Why? When I used the placeholders (now commented) it gave me no results. I'll post a second question if I can't fix it.

The question I wanted to ask here is:
This function successfully finds documents when users search for them. But when a field is an integer, no results are given. I tried to replace the LIKE with a "=" and removed both quotes and %. Then the users could successfully search for numbers in the integer fields. But then users can't search for the string fields anymore.
Any ideas?

Comment: You can just do a check on `$searchterm` to see if it is an int, then alter the query based on that.

Comment: Is it not possible to do this in n1ql? Like some special quotes that work with both? ATM I'm converting all integers to strings (it's a test db) and it works, but your workaround sounds better, I'll try it later.

Comment: No in PHP itself. Something with the `is_int($searchterm)` and changing your raw query string based on that conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.
I just added a TOSTRING() in the n1ql statement and it now works for both string and int.

```
public static function findByPageAndFieldContains($recordsPerPage, $page, $field, $searchterm) {
    $query = CouchbaseN1qlQuery::fromString('SELECT * FROM `public_portal` WHERE `collection`=$collection AND TOSTRING('.$field.') LIKE "%'.$searchterm.'%" ORDER BY `_id` limit $limit offset $offset');
    $query->options['$collection'] = static::COLLECTION_NAME;
    //$query->options['$field'] = $field;
    $query->options['$limit'] = $recordsPerPage;
    $query->options['$offset'] = $recordsPerPage*($page-1);
    //$query->options['$searchterm'] = $searchterm;

    $result = DB::getDB()->query($query);
    //var_dump($query);
    //var_dump($result);
    $objects = array();
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $object = new static($row->{"public_portal"});
        $object->setId($row->{"public_portal"}->{"_id"});
        $objects[] = $object;
    }
    //var_dump($objects);
    return $objects;
    return $result;
}
```